# increasing whitespace - css background

Tags: css, joomla

i am very new to CSS. i need to increase the width of the white space of this:

http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

the css file is here:

http://yoursdproperty.com/templates/pjo_joomlaforall/css/template_css.css

how do know which element to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use firebug. it is a firefox add-on. just download and enable it and click an element to inspect it. you will instantly know everything related to it.

Edit

On you page, you just need to replace the image ../images/bgr.png with a wider white space in it.

Comment: perhaps you can also answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173547/css-increasing-size-of-holder-or-what-ever-its-called

Answer (score 2):

The page you link to is using the following as a background image:

http://yoursdproperty.com/templates/pjo_joomlaforall/images/bgr.png

To increase the width of the white space, you'll need to modify that image. 
`#background_right` is the element that contains the background image.

Also, per Umar's answer, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).